Find email address from google user id
I am building a google chat app with an interactive dialog having a dropdown like below. The formInputs returns users in the form users\123456789. How do I get the email address of the user from users\123456789?
        "selectionInput": {
          "name": "contacts",
          "type": "MULTI_SELECT",
          "label": "Selected contacts",
          "multiSelectMaxSelectedItems": 5,
          "multiSelectMinQueryLength": 1,
          "platformDataSource": {
            "commonDataSource": "USER"
          }
        }
      }


Please provide a minimal reproducible example especially on how you got to the point where you got the users\123456789 output. Also, please confirm if you are using Google Apps Script for this?

Yes, I am using google apps script. The above form field returns users\12345678  when the form is submitted
